# How to show a set is a norm compact subset

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

At this [paper](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), page $128$, in Theorem $3.1$, there are two parts which I don't understand how the authors got them:

$(1)$ In the first sentence of the proof, why the set
$$K=\{ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{t_nx_n}:0 \leq t_n \leq 1 \}$$ is a norm compact subset of $X$?

$(2)$ Why $\beta(\phi_n)=x_n$?

Comment: (1) Because the author assumes it is. This is part of his "Let" statement, not a condition that follows from it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Perhaps I should ask why can we find such sequence in which the set $K$ is compact.

Comment: Yes. It is very important to ask the question you actually want answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), let $(y_n)$ be a dense sequence in $S_X$ (the unit sphere of $X$), define $(x_n)$ by $x_n := 2^{-n}y_n$, then the span of $(x_n)$ is dense in $X$ and $K_0 := \{x_n \mid n \in \mathbf N\} \cup \{0\}$, is compact, as the sequence $x_n$ converges to $0$. Now, $K_1 := \operatorname{\overline{conv}}K_0$ is still compact, as $K$ is a closed subset of $K_1$, $K$ is also compact.

For (2), note that $\beta \colon \mathcal F(X) \to X$ is linear and continuous, hence
\begin{align*}
  \beta(\phi_n) &= \beta\left(\int_{H_n} \delta\bigl(x_n + S_n(t)\bigr) - \delta\bigl(S_n(t)\bigr)\, d\lambda_n(t)\right)\\
   &= \int_{H_n} \beta\Bigl(\delta\bigl(x_n + S_n(t)\bigr) - \delta\bigl(S_n(t)\bigr)\Bigr)\, d\lambda_n(t)\\
   &= \int_{H_n} \beta\delta\bigl(x_n + S_n(t)\bigr) - \beta\delta\bigl(S_n(t)\bigr)\, d\lambda_n(t)\\
   &= \int_{H_n} \bigl(x_n + S_n(t) - S_n(t)\bigr)\,d\lambda_n(t)\\
   &= \int_{H_n} 1 \, d\lambda_n(t)\, \cdot x_n\\
   &= x_n
\end{align*}

Comment: Second equation, why can we bring in the $\beta$ function into the integral? Because of continuity of $\beta$?

Comment: Continuity and linearity. For Bochner integrable $f \colon \Omega \to X$ and $T \in L(X,Y)$ we have that $T\circ f$ is Bochner integrable and $$ T \int_\Omega f(x)\, dx = \int_{\Omega} T\bigl(f(x)\bigr) \, dx $$

Comment: Why is the set $K$ closed?

Comment: Why $K \subseteq K_1$?